# Axios to php api - POST form empty

Tags: php, post, axios

I'm sure this is an easy one, hopefully it's easy. In setting up axios (with VUE) and trying to post something, anything, POST is not received. Postman works fine, my vue app with Axios however does not, the POST array arrives empty.

The outgoing request payload in devtools has the variables (at the moment just 'test'='test.

From Vue

```
      this.$axios.post("http://localhost/api/process.php?action=addEntry", {
        test:"test"
      }).then(function (response) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          alert("error");
          alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
      return
    },
```

From PHP Api - process.php

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: User-Agent, Sec-Fetch-Mode, Referer, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8'); 

echo (var_dump($_POST['test']));
echo (var_dump($_POST));
```

Output

> The POST is not available.

The response
[image: response]

The headers

[image: headers]

Comment: In which method, you add your Axios code it should be it `mounted` method if so try to import axios in your component and write `axios.post('')`

Comment: Can you share your .vue file? I think something is missing!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
axios.post("urlapi", 
                 data: {
                    foo: 'bar', // This is the body part
                  }, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(function(res){
                console.log(res);
            }).catch();
```

This works for me.